# How to use OpenSSL 1.1.1 to implement HDF-Extract?

Tags: openssl, hkdf

I'm trying to implement parts of the QUIC RFC and they note:

```
   initial_salt = 0xc3eef712c72ebb5a11a7d2432bb46365bef9f502
   initial_secret = HKDF-Extract(initial_salt,
                                 client_dst_connection_id)
```

I was just wondering, how does one map this to here: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_hkdf_md.html

I get this:

> EVP_PKEY_HKDEF_MODE_EXTRACT_ONLY
>   In this mode calling EVP_PKEY_derive(3) will just perform the extract operation. The value returned will be the intermediate fixed-length pseudorandom key K.
>
> The digest, key and salt values must be set before a key is derived or an error occurs.

But I'm confused here. I can see how to set the mode, the algorithm, the salt but I'm lost which where to set the `client_dst_connection_id`.

Comment: Welcome to crypto.stackexchange - This appears to be a programming question rather than a question about the internals/mathematics of a cryptographic algorithm. Programming questions belong on StackOverflow, even if they use cryptography. I can migrate this there for you.

Comment: So sorry about that! Wasn't aware. Thank you for migrating this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HKDF is described in RFC5869 which defines the HKDF-Extract operation like this:

> HKDF-Extract(salt, IKM) -> PRK
>
> Options:
>         Hash     a hash function; HashLen denotes the length of the
>                  hash function output in octets
>
> Inputs:
>         salt     optional salt value (a non-secret random value);
>                  if not provided, it is set to a string of HashLen zeros.
>         IKM      input keying material
>
> Output:
>         PRK      a pseudorandom key (of HashLen octets)

So, the second parameter (`client_dst_connection_id` in this case) is the "input keying material".

On the OpenSSL man page you linked to you can see that the keying material can be set using `EVP_PKEY_CTX_set1_hkdf_key()`.

Note that the man page also says the following for `EVP_PKEY_HKDEF_MODE_EXTRACT_ONLY`:

> The digest, key and salt values must be set before a key is derived or
>   an error occurs.

So, the key and salt values are clear. You will also need to specify the digest in use via `EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_hkdf_md()`

Comment: Thank you so much! This absolutely works for me and it even passes the test vectors as outlined by the RFC!