# EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id returns NULL openssl 1.1.1g

Tags: c++, openssl, hkdf

I am using openssl 1.1.1g to implement parts of the quic RFC.
I followed the suggestions in the following link
[How to use OpenSSL 1.1.1 to implement HDF-Extract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188168/how-to-use-openssl-1-1-1-to-implement-hdf-extract)
But the very first call (EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id) fails with error
139800057870304:error:0609D09C:lib(6):func(157):reason(156):pmeth_lib.c:166:

Error code 156 (if that is what it means) as defined in evperr.h is

```
# define EVP_F_EVP_PKEY_CTX_DUP                           156
```

Any idea why this would be the case? Here is the snippet of code

```
   EVP_PKEY_CTX *pctx;
    pctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_HKDF, NULL);
    if (pctx == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Null context " << std::endl;
        ERR_print_errors_fp (stderr);
        EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(pctx);
        return false;

    }

Thanks!

dependencies

ldd libQP.so
   linux-vdso.so.1 
        librt.so.1 
        libpthread.so.0 
        libdl.so.2 
        liblog4cxx.so.10
        libssl.so.10
        libcrypto.so.10
        libgcf1_pt3.so.6.3.1 
        libACE.so.6.3.1
        libboost_system.so.1.53.0
        libboost_timer.so.1.53.0
        libboost_thread-mt.so.1.53.0
        libboost_system-mt.so.1.53.0
        libstdc++.so.6
        libm.so.6
        libgcc_s.so.1
        libc.so.6
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        libaprutil-1.so.0
        libldap_r-2.4.so.2
        liblber-2.4.so.2
        libexpat.so.1
        libdb-5.3.so
        libapr-1.so.0
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
        libkrb5.so.3
        libcom_err.so.2
        libk5crypto.so.3
        libz.so.1
        libboost_chrono.so.1.53.0
        libuuid.so.1
        libcrypt.so.1
        libresolv.so.2
        libsasl2.so.3
        libssl3.so
        libsmime3.so
        libnss3.so
        libnssutil3.so
        libplds4.so
        libplc4.so
        libnspr4.so
        libkrb5support.so.0
        libkeyutils.so.1
        libfreebl3.so
        libselinux.so.1 
        libpcre.so.1
```

Comment: I tested this snippet and it worked just fine. Could you show us your includes, the compilation flags and the `ldd` output of your binary (e.g.: `ldd my_binary`)?

Comment: Lucas Thanks for your response.Lucas Thanks for your response. It is a shared library and the code is executed via a unit test framework. The dependencies list is below. I noticed that there are multiple ssl and crypto sos linked that I was not aware of. Not sure if this is causing the issue

Comment: I suggest you update your question with this information. It'll be easier to read.

Comment: Thanks! Done. It was a useful exercise.

Comment: Are you sure you are using OpenSSL 1.1.1 to build your library? Looks like `libcrypto.so.10` is 1.0.2.

Comment: Right. So i thought. I am in the process of figuring out all the other dependency creeps. I added this shared library as part of a larger project that i am new to. Thanks for the pointers.